# Travel Winterbash 2018 - join us!

Tags: discussion, fun, winter-bash

[Winterbash](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/) is back for 2018, and there's always some friendly travel competition to see who can get the best/most awesome/most hats.

[The Travel Leaderboard](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/travel.stackexchange.com)

Currently, the rankings are as follows:

- [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=summary), [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo) on 13 hats.
- [Nean Der Thal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/10051/nean-der-thal) on 11 hats
- [Sue](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/57178/sue) on 9 hats
- [jcaron](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/30703/jcaron) on 7 hats
- [Dirty Flow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2560/dirty-flow) on 8 hats
- [ajd](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/32143/ajd) on 6 hats
- [Sakina](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/88123/sakina) on 6 hats
- ..several on 5 hats.

Please join [the travel chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) for tips on how to get them, and to see if you can help each other achieve the tricky ones!